# How to display the value of each bar in multi bar barcharts per row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Iam tring to display the value of each bar, **problem is that for each row there is 3 columns therefore 3 bars per row**

So i can't just use this following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i, v in enumerate(df.values):      
       plt.text(i, v, str(v), color='blue', fontweight='bold')
```

---

and results in error when try to `df.plot()`
saying `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

---

**That's the df**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://cocl.us/datascience_survey_data')
df = df.set_index('Unnamed: 0')
df = df.sort_values(['Very interested'], ascending=False)
df = df / 2233 * 100
df = round(df, 2)
```

---

[image: dataframe]

---

**This is my current plot**

`df.plot(kind='bar', color=['#5cb85c', '#5bc0de', '#d9534f'], width=0.8, figsize=(10, 8))`

[image: dataframe bar plotting]

---

That's what iam tring to acheive

[image]

---

Comment: [ax.annotate](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html)

Comment: thanks it works, but how can i fully view x labels (xticks), it's cutten and no matter how i increase figsize stays the same 
@It_is_Chris

Comment: you can see how cutten it is from my first plotting picture